# jPanel scrolls body when reached the end

Tags: jquery, scroll, jpanel, jpanelmenu

I'm using the jQuery [jPanelMenu](http://jpanelmenu.com/) plugin for a website. Since the navigation is relatively long, I get a scrollbar on the panel. However, once I reach the end of said panel, I start scrolling the body as well. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have to prevent scrolling of parent element, you have to use event stopPropagation().

Check the JSFiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCvD3/268/)

```
$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel','#jPanelMenu-menu', function(ev) {
var $this = $(this),
    scrollTop = this.scrollTop,
    scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight,
    height = $this.height(),
    delta = (ev.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
        ev.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
        ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta),
    up = delta > 0;

var prevent = function() {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}

if (!up && -delta > scrollHeight - height - scrollTop) {
    $this.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
    return prevent();
} else if (up && delta > scrollTop) {
    $this.scrollTop(0);
    return prevent();
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rushee. The stopPropagation seems to be the only option possible. Bounty will be awarded as soon as it becomes available.